# Can't convert month number to name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I've the following line of SQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(MONTH('YEAR-MM-01'), CONCAT(' ', YEAR('YEAR-MM-01'))), '  |  ') AS period;
```

It retuns for example `3 2019`. I want the 3 to be replaced with March

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: What does your question have to do with your sample code?

Comment: Is there a way to modify this and return the month as name instead of the number?

Comment: No idea what your sample code is supposed to represent. But if you have actual datetimes you can use [DATENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get the name of the date part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
select 
    concat(
        datename(month, getdate()),
        ' ',
        year(getdate()),
        ' | '
    ) as period
```

If your output used to be `3 2019 |`, your query would look like this to get `March 2019 |`:

```
select 
    concat(
        datename(month, cast('2019-03-01' as date)),
        ' ',
        year(cast('2019-03-01' as date)),
        ' | '
    ) as period
```

Comment: @sterrek . . . What does this have to do with your question?  You have a sample string of `'3 2019'`, which really has nothing to do with `getdate()`.

Answer (score 3):

Just because nobody mentioned `format()`

To be clear, format() has some great functionality, but the performance can suffer.  It should be used **sparingly**.

**Example**

```
Select format(GetDate(),'MMMM, yyyy | ')
```

**Returns**

```
April, 2019 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, can be useful to!

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
datename(month, '2000/01/02')
```

You can get the month name:

```
select  concat(concat(datename(month,'YEAR-MM-01'),concat(' ',year('YEAR-MM-01'))),'  |  ') as period;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for your example:

```
select datename(month, cast(replace('1 ' + v.str, ' ', '-') as date)) + right(str, 5)
from (values ('3 2019')) v(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just format the date/datetime value using `FORMAT` function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMMM yyyy')
```

Complete list of format specifiers is [available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

Answer (score 0):

Use DATENAME instead to get the name of the month.

SELECT CONCAT(DATENAME(mm,'YEAR-MM-01'  ), ' ', YEAR('YEAR-MM-01'))